# How do we include Corda Finance Currencies as a dependency?

Tags: gradle, dependencies, build.gradle, corda

Now that the Corda finance jar has been split into corda-finance-contracts and corda-finance-workflows, how do I add corda-finance-currencies to my CorDapp using my deployNodes task in my build.gradle?

Right now I am getting the following error message when I attempt to deploy:

`Attempted to find dependent attachment for class net/corda/finance/Currencies, but could not find a suitable candidate.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you importing corda-finance-workflows correctly? As it's class is in there:

[image]

Comment: Hey Arsalan - I was not. But now I am! Thanks for your help.